# Set a value within a closure swift

Tags: swift, closures

I am creating an app with swift. I have created a class, "generatorID" (the aim : return a random ID from a database)  :

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class generatorID: NSObject {

var idRandom = String()

func setRandomNumber(maxNumber: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(arc4random()) % maxNumber
}

func setRandomIdUser()-> String {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://localhost:3000/api/users")
        .responseJSON{ (request, response, data, error) in
            var randomNumber = self.setRandomNumber(data!.count)
            self.idRandom = data![randomNumber].objectForKey("id")! as String
    }
    return idRandom
}
}
```

The problem, setRandomIdUser() returns nothing. I would like to know how to set a value for the variable idRandom within the closure in my function setRandomIdUser(). When I put

```
println(self.idRandom)
```

in the closure after

```
self.idRandom = data![randomNumber].objectForKey("id")! as String
```

, I can see a random ID.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Swift not update the variables outside the closure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394699/why-does-swift-not-update-the-variables-outside-the-closure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Alamofire.request` runs on another thread and wait for data.So your `closure`  will execute some time after and you are returning before the `closure` runs.

Comment: so, how to fix it?